# Parse error in haskell code, can't figure out why

Tags: haskell

**Updated:** Removed code unrelated to error because this is homework and other students might see it.

I'm working on a homework assignment that uses haskell in order to play connect four.  The game board is provided, as is the list that contains moves.  I'm new to haskell and I don't understand why I'm getting a parse error on line 20.  I'm also having issues with completing the code that checks for connect four, so any help on either of those two problems would be greatly appreciated.

The error I get is:

```
:20:40: error :
    parse error on input ‘=’
    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
    e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
```

In the following code, the line causing the error is marked with a comment:

```
onePlayerManyMoves :: [[Char]] -> [Int] -> [[Char]]
onePlayerManyMoves :: [[Char]] -> [Int] -> [[Char]]
onePlayerManyMoves [] _ = []
onePlayerManyMoves game [] = game  -- **parse error here**
if connectFour
  onePlayerManyMoves game (move:moves) = game
else
  onePlayerManyMoves game (move:moves) = play game '1' move, onePlayerManyMoves game (move:moves) = game moves
where connectFour = checkFour game
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error you're getting?

Comment: :20:40: error :
 parse error on input `='
Perhaps you need a 'let ' in a 'do ' block ?
 e . g . 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'

Comment: Are there really backticks in the middle of your code? Please fix your formatting. I can't figure out what's real code and what's just a formatting screw-up on StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  I see you edited your question to delete all the text.  I understand why you did it (to avoid giving other students the answer), but this kind of edit leaves a useless question laying around that won't benefit anyone else.    I have rolled back your changes but edited your code down to the minimum necessary.  If you still feel uncomfortable having the code up, you can delete your question entirely, but see https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question first.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring spurious ``` in the source code. Let's look at these lines:

```
if connectFour
  onePlayerManyMoves game (move:moves) = game
else
  onePlayerManyMoves game (move:moves) = play game '1' move, onePlayerManyMoves game (move:moves) = game moves
```

This is not how the conditional works in Haskell. First, it is an *expression*. Not a statement, not a declaration, not anything else. An expression. (And there's `then` keyword which is not optional). You cannot have a conditional pattern binding like that. You need a conditional expression:

```
onePlayerManyMoves game (move:moves) = if connectFour then ... else ...
```

Next thing, let's look what goes in the `else` branch.

```
play game '1' move, onePlayerManyMoves game (move:moves) = game moves
```

I have no idea what this could possibly mean. There is no comma operator in Haskell. It is very unclear what you are trying to do here.

There are many other errors further down, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks! This is my first post on here, so I wasn't sure how I was supposed to edit it (in reference to the ```` throughout the code.  I'm just learning how to post on here!)
I appreciate the feedback! This is also my first time working with any functional language, so I've been struggling with the syntax a lot.  I'll make those changes and see where I get!

Comment: Just for clarity, there is a comma operator (tuple constructor) @n.m. though it's a bit unusual in that you need the brackets too to use it

Comment: @ATayler there are commas all over the place tbf, lists, tuples, list comprehensions etc, but no standalone operator.

Comment: @n.m. you're right, checked the language report and the tuple constructor is technically not an operator, which when I think about it harder makes sense :)